# margin-bottom is not working and showing gap (html and css)

Tags: html, css, header, margin

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 200px;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 1500px;
      /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

in the **.navbar** selector, I have added margin-bottom:200px; why it does not show any effect. why its not placing a gap of 200px between the navbar and contents below it.
I am trying to show gap between them and i tried margin-bottom. just wanted to know why its not working.
I have provided the code below.

Comment: The ```margin``` property doesn't work on ```fixed``` elements. Alternatively, you can give a ```margin-top``` to ```main```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a `position: fixed` rule specified. I replaced you with the `position: sticky` rule. Your `margin-bottom` is now working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      /*position: fixed;*/
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 200px;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 1500px;
      /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```